# Concord Grape Vine Progress Question

Tags: grape-vine

I am trying to grow a grape vine (Concord) for the first time. I was busy for a long time, so I potted the vine in a smaller pot (probably 12" diameter and 12" deep) and it really took off.  After several weeks, I uprooted the vine and planted it in the ground.  It's been in the ground for several weeks and is definitely growing.  But it doesn't seem as vigorous as it had in the pot, and I'm especially interested in getting feedback on how the vine looks at present, especially the very top of the vine.  My suspicion is that it's weak, and that weakness is evident by the flimsiness at the top and also the coloration at the top. If that's the case, I'm worried that the vine might never be strong enough to support robust fruit output, even if it stays alive and grows some.  Are these concerns valid given the images I'm attaching?  Should I assume that this vine is basically lost and try again anew next year?  Thanksenter image description here
[image]

Comment: Growing tip looks pretty normal. Given the poor thing has been transplanted after starting growth (best to put them straight where they are going to live, if that's an option "next time") it's doing pretty well, really. Read up on grapevine pruning before next winter (yes, winter) so you can set it on the right track on that front, which is a big deal for getting fruit from grapes.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You need more patience. It is growing a lot more roots now it is in the ground.  Many vines don't do a whole lot the first few years they are planted as they are getting a good root system. Just leave it and ensure adequate water for the first year while it is establishing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!